# Vue 2 Moving Window with Keyboard Navigation

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a list in my program. In this list, you press ArrowUp or ArrowDown to navigate between the items that are generated with a v-for in said list. When you use the arrows to navigate the list, a counter is used to know which item inside this list is the "selected" one. My current problem is: When you "select" an item that is outside your view, the Browser's Window doesn't follow it down, allowing the selection to keep "going down" this list, but the user isn't able to see the other selected items.

I've tried messing around with the focus() function, but I don't know how to focus() a specific item without using the ref atribute, which I also can't seem to implement since it's being generated with v-for.
Here's my current table:

```
<table class="table table-striped p-0 m-0" v-show="pedidos.length > 0">
            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr class="">
                    <th>Cliente Emissor</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <!-- <th>Endereço</th> -->
                    <!-- <th>Valor</th> -->
                    <th>Data Emissão</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template v-for="(pedido, index) in pedidos">
                    <itemPedido  :pedido="pedido" :key="index" :endereco="endereco" :class="[(navegacaoAtual == index) ? 'teste' : '']" ref="teste"></itemPedido>
                    <itemEdit @atualizarListaPedidos="atualizarListaPedidos" @atualizarStatusModal="atualizarStatusModal" class="animation-dropdown" :pedido="pedido" :key="pedido.nome"></itemEdit>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here's the current navigateWithArrows() function I've made:

```
navegarSetas(key) {
        if (this.navegacaoSetasAtiva == false) {
            this.navegacaoSetasAtiva = true
            this.navegacaoAtual = 0
        } else if (this.modalAtivado == false && this.navegacaoSetasAtiva == true) {
            if (key == 'ArrowDown' && this.navegacaoAtual < this.pedidos.length - 1) {
                this.navegacaoAtual++
                Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
                    let teste1 = this.$refs.teste[this.navegacaoAtual]
                    teste1.$el.focus()
                })
            } else if (key == 'ArrowUp' && this.navegacaoAtual <= this.pedidos.length && this.navegacaoAtual > 0) {
                this.navegacaoAtual--
            } else if (key == 'Enter') {
                let pedidoSelecionado = this.pedidos[this.navegacaoAtual].id
                Event.$emit('changeShow', pedidoSelecionado)
            }
        }
    },
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After taking a break and resuming my search, I stumbled upon something that did exactly what I wanted: the scrollIntoView() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView